# How to understand pandas .apply(axis='columns')?

Tags: python, pandas, function, parameters, apply

Below is an answer code I received from Kaggle Pandas course.

```
def stars(row):
    if row.country == 'Canada':
        return 3
    elif row.points >= 95:
        return 3
    elif row.points >= 85:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

star_ratings_2 = reviews.apply(stars, axis='columns')
```

The question goes like this:

> We'd like to host these wine reviews on our website, but a rating system ranging from 80 to 100 points is too hard to understand - we'd like to translate them into simple star ratings. A score of 95 or higher counts as 3 stars, a score of at least 85 but less than 95 is 2 stars. Any other score is 1 star.

> Also, the Canadian Vintners Association bought a lot of ads on the site, so any wines from Canada should automatically get 3 stars, regardless of points.

> Create a series star_ratings with the number of stars corresponding to each review in the dataset.

The dataset looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fma7N.png)

My question is:
`star_ratings_2 = reviews.apply(stars, axis='columns')`  
Why `axis='columns` instead of `axis='rows'`? since the `stars()` functions has to process `country` and `points` columns of a row, shouldn't we pass a row to the `stars()` function?

I just didn't expect the correct answer will be `axis='columns'`, I ve asked around including ChatGPT, but there is no good answer for me. ChatGPT even think that I am right where the `axis='rows'` should be correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its ask for a solution

Comment: Side note on "*ChatGPT even think that I am right*", ChatGPT doesn't **think** anything, it just puts words together in a way that statistically matches the corpora on which it was trained, and on your interaction with it. **Do not** rely on ChatGPT for anything related to logic or programming, you'll risk huge mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology is maybe misleading. However the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) documentation is pretty clear:

> axis: {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> > Axis along which the function is applied:
> >
> > 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
> >
> > **1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.**

You can make the parallel with aggregation functions: `df.sum(axis=1)` takes each row and aggregates it into a single value. This is the same here: `apply` on `axis=1`/`axis='columns'` takes each row and performs something.

Comment: Thank you, therefore it made some sense, but it is quite weird that "1 or ‘columns’: apply a function to each row.", why won't it just set the parameter 'columns' mean function apply to each column, does anyone know why?

Comment: @AhDean there is no absolutely objective "why", it's a developer choice. I could bet that, if the other choice had been done, someone would prefer the current way. Just know how this works and stick to it ;)